# Store a Javascript variable in next variable statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sub_category").click(function()
  {
        var main_cat = $("input[name='category_form_cat_1']:checked").val();
        var sub_cat_form1 = $("input[name='subcategory_form_cat_1']:checked").val();    
        $("input[name='subcategory_form_cat_1'][value=sub_cat_form1]").attr("checked",true);​
        $.ajax
        ({
            data: {'cat':main_cat,'sub_cat':sub_cat_form1},
            url: "ajax_files/events-select.php",
            type: 'GET',                
            success: function(data) 
            {
                $("#displayedresults").html(data);
                $('#loading_spinner').hide();
                $('#loading_text').hide();
                $('#loading_row').hide();
                $('#displayedresults').show();
                //$('.button_export').show();
                //$("a.button_export").attr("href", string);
            }
        });
        return false;
  });
});
```

I need to store this line value in the next one

```
var sub_cat_form1 = $("input[name='subcategory_form_cat_1']:checked").val();    
$("input[name='subcategory_form_cat_1'][value=sub_cat_form1]").attr("checked",true);​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
   var sub_cat_form1 = $("input[name='subcategory_form_cat_1']:checked").val();    
   $("input[value="+sub_cat_form1 +"]").attr("checked",true);​
```